# Responsive Table Shrinking On Mobile

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, html-table

I've been creating a table for adding to a WordPress site. As the site is responsive, the table should be somewhat too.

So I've been creating my table and in the editor (I use Visual Studio Code) it was responding perfectly, but I thought I'd better test it in Chrome. I saved it, opened it in Chrome, and then inspected it with the Mobile view turned on.

Although the `min-width` set on the cells, which should of almost filled the width of the mobile view, the cells hardly pasted the halfway mark.

So I created a new table as below, and the same happened.

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td style="min-width: 200px;">Min Width 200px</td>
    <td style="min-width: 300px;">Min Width 300px</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[image]

Why is it doing this? What can I do to fix this?

Comment: FF doesn't shrink...

Comment: @dippas So a bug with Chrome then?

Comment: I am having the same exact issue in 2020. I suppose that if this was a bug it would had been fixed by now. Is there a reason for this behavior in responsive mode? It seems a bit counterintuitive as it shrinks the whole table (and the fonts inside, etc.) proportionally instead of making the columns shrink horizontally while maintaining legible type size...

Comment: @glitchform see the accepted answer below. It's due to the different browsers setting different default scales. By declaring a scale, you override those defaults.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I noticed Chrome started scaling everything down in device mode in certain cases (I'm not sure of the exact conditions, so if anyone know please pitch in).

I fixed it in my site by adding `minimum-scale=1` to the viewport meta value:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1">
```

Comment: Andreyu, thaaaaaanks!!!! you rock!!!! it works and that is what I need!!!!!

Comment: This worked like a dream! for some reason, the HTML in my page was getting shrunk really weirdly when switching to the dev tools mobile view. Now it works.